# Using a bookmark in URL in asp.net mvc web page does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am navigating to a page with bookmark - http://www.makemeok.com/ncr/palam-colony-hospitals/singhal-hospital-jabfc#description

The page is templated using ASP.NET MVC Razor engine.

The bookmark - description exists on the page. But, the page does not scroll down to the bookmark on document load. Any reasons why the bookmark is not working?

```
<a id="description" name="description"></a>
```

Comment: show your View please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your page, that situated on link.

You have 2 `a` tags with `id` and `name` with value `description`.

That's why it's not working. Just change one of them to

```
<a id="description2" name="description2">...</a>
```

And everything will work.

Comment: That was the mobile view :) We reused the partial views for the desktop template and mobile template. Thanks for the pointer. Let me try it out.